# access variables outside of slot. pass variables between slots. concatenate string variables in QT

Tags: qt, variables, parameter-passing, signals-slots, qstring

New to Qt. Can you help me understand how to concatenate two QStrings from two different Line Edits?

I have a gui with two line edits. a prefix text, and a number text. I would like to combine the prefix and number value into a single string.

```
//connect the line edit slots to signals
    QObject::connect(ui->prefixLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
                             this, SLOT(prefixChanged()));
    QObject::connect(ui->startNumberLineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),
                             this, SLOT(startNumChanged()));

//functions to run when line edit is changed
void MainWindow::prefixChanged(){
    QString prefixText = ui->prefixLineEdit->text();

}
void MainWindow::startNumChanged(){
    QString startNumberText = ui->startNumberLineEdit->text();

    //combine prefix and start number??
    QString combined = (prefixText + startNumberText);
    ui->statusbar->showMessage(combined);

}
```

I guess the question in general is how do I share variables between slots? I have read about QSignalMapper, potentially making a proxy slot to pass arguments to, and looked at the .args() function for QString. but that's all sort of beyond me right now.

Do I have to make these variables public in order to access them out of the slot function? I thought that was sort of frowned upon?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can have private member variables, though in your case you can access the text from any `MainWindow` member function with your `ui` variable: `ui->prefixLineEdit->text()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like that, just accessing `ui` where you need:

```
void MainWindow::startNumChanged(){
    QString startNumberText = ui->startNumberLineEdit->text();
    QString prefixText = ui->prefixLineEdit->text();

    //combine prefix and start number
    QString combined = prefixText + startNumberText;
    ui->statusbar->showMessage(combined);
}
```

You can move this code to some function and call it from each slot if you need.

In more complex cases, you would need private variables of class in header:

```
QString startNumberText;
QString prefixText;
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Following the answer from demonplus, I crafted this function:

```
void MainWindow::combineOutputName(){

    QString prefixText = ui->prefixLineEdit->text();
    int incrementValue = ui->incrementSpinBox->value();
    QString startNumberValue = ui->startNumberLineEdit->text();

    int newValue = startNumberValue.toInt() + incrementValue;

    ui->exampleLabel->setText(QString::number(newValue));
}
```

which accomplishes pulling together the input from different UI elements into one variable.